# "Almost" a supermartingale

Tags: probability, martingales

Good morning,

imagine you have an adapted process $\{S(t):t\geq 1\}$ with $S(t)\geq 0$ and $E(S(t))<\infty$ for all $t$. The following holds (for every $t$):

$E[S(t+1)-S(t)|\mathcal{F}_t]\leq O\left(\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}\right)$.

So the process $\{S(t):t\geq 1\}$ is not a (non-negative) supermartingale, even if the term on the right-hand side of last equality tends to $0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. So the martingale property is satisfied "in the limit of large time". The point is that I need $(S(t))_t$ to be a supermartingale in order to apply the Martingale Conv. Thm. Do you know any trick to solve a problem of this type?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, we cannot expect that $S_t$ converges almost surely as $t \to \infty$. Consider, for instance, $$S_t := \sum_{j=2}^{t-1} \frac{1}{t \ln t}.$$ The situation would be different if you had an estimate of the form $$\mathbb{E}(S(t+1)-S(t) \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \leq O \left( \frac{1}{t^{\alpha}} \right)$$ for some $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer saz. Indeed, as you pointed out, I proved that we have convergence if I substitute $\ln(t)$ with $(\ln(t))^s$ for $s>1$. However, in this case I get an a.s. convergence to $0$, thus "suggesting" a logarithmic rate of convergence. So I find it a bit strange actually.

Comment: What do you mean by "a.s. convergence to $0$"? Why should the supermartingale converge to $0$?

Comment: Sorry when I wrote "we have convergence if I substitute..." I was not referring to $S(t)$. Actually the problem is a bit different. I have a sequence of random variables, $(D(t))_t$ and I showed that $D(t)/(\ln(t))^s$ converges almost surely to $0$ when $s>1$. To do so, I used a (super-)martingale (our $S(t)$). Now I am trying to get something similar for $s=1$, but I do not find such a supermartingale; I stuck to the point mentioned at the very beginning.

Comment: Without any further information on the random variables $D_t$ this is pretty hopeless to answer. For instance $D(t) := \ln t$ satisfies $D(t)/\ln(t)^s \to 0$ for $s>1$ but not for $s=1$.

Comment: The random variables $D(t)$ are such that $E[D(t)]<\infty$ for all $t$ and $E[D(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t]=D(t)\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+\frac{t+1}{t^2}$. Moreover, $D(t)\leq D(t+1)$ for all $t$.